# xcode error - Jsonkit.m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, jsonkit

I'm using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) Objective-C library.

But its causing an error  in JSONKit.m while I compile the source.

I've used `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag to compile non-arc code.

The error is inside **JSONKit.m** file, pointing to the filepath/NSString (isa).

What should I do to avoid this error.

Comment: Why you using the old framework which is not continue for development. if you are looking for JASON parsing go for native one, also if you still wants to go ahead add the code always for that you are trying to do.

Comment: Venkat, please use the exact file name while writing the question. Secondly, can you copy-paste the exact error here in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Please use native class [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) for parsing JSON its more helpful rather than relying on third party components.